# Visual Studio Windows Forms sizing is off

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a board game using C# in Visual Studio.

I am using pictureboxes as pieces and I change their location according to their dice roll.
The locations are really important to my game.

But for some reason, when I test the app, the sizing and locations are way different than in the design view while editing (see images, espacially the image differences are visible)

Is there any way to get around this and get better sizing/locations on my application?

[The design view while editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOuNs.jpg)

[The app while testing (Started)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJock.jpg)

Comment: (it took me forever to notice that the differences between the images are in the small grey rectangles in the center-left and center-right)

Comment: If your form at runtime looks different than the design view, you must have some code making that happen.  We can't help you without seeing the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of what the differences exactly are?  You could load screenshots into something else and draw arrows.  Is the entire board one image?  Or is it being drawn dynamically?

Comment: Win10 font scaling is evil. What is the ScaleMode property on the form set? See https://i.imgur.com/UnPmpml.png for example.

Comment: Note that yellow bar in the 1st screenshot.  You do want to click it as long as DPI scaling is still mysterious.

Comment: @ja72 it is indeed set to font. Does it have to be set to something else?